# jquery, how to trigger function from a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

i have this example:

```
<script>
$('.myvideos').live('click', function() {
    $('#myvideos').trigger('click');
    var ide = '123';
    function ajax_request() {
        $('#placeholder').load("test.php?id=ide");
    }
});
</script>
```

how can i  trigger the `ajax_request` function after `$('#myvideos').trigger('click');` happens and pass the `ide` var to load link?

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<script>
$('.myvideos').live('click', function() {
    var ide = '123';
    ajax_request(ide);
});

function ajax_request(ide) {
        $('#placeholder').load("test.php?id="+ide);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: what about the `ide` var, does it know that is a var or i have to append it using `+`

Comment: sorry didn't see the var ide. Updated. Thanks @Seybsen

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
  $('.myvideos').live('click', function() {
    var ide = '123';
    ajax_request(ide) 
  });

  function ajax_request(ide) {
    $('#placeholder').load("test.php?id=" + ide);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to put the AJAX call inside a function

```
<script>
$('.myvideos').live('click', function() {
    $('#myvideos').trigger('click');
    var ide = '123';
    $('#placeholder').load("test.php?id=" + ide);
});
</script>
```